# Undo doesn't work in Details interface of a Master-Details interface project

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a Master-Details interface.  The Master is a table view with an associated model, array controller, and add/remove buttons.  The Details interface is made up of numerous individual table views, each with its own individual model, array controller, and add/remove buttons.  The table view at the top in the screen shot is the Master.

[Screen shot of interface builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Dhy.png)

The Master array controller is bound to file’s owner and the associated array, which in this case is an instance of Document and airports.

[Master array controller binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey3d1.png)

Each separate Details array controller is bound to the Master array controller, Controller Key of Selection,  and the Details’ associated array that are properties of the Master model.

[example of Details array controller binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0zrS.png)

I have this set up so that the Add buttons for all of the Details table views are not active unless a row has been selected in the Master.

[Example of Details Add Button Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EfSI.png)

I have the undo code in Document.swift

```
private var KVOContext: Int = 0
private var currentAirportIndex = 0

class Document: NSDocument, NSWindowDelegate {

    ...

@IBAction func addAirports(sender: NSButton) {
    let windowController = windowControllers[0]
    let window = windowController.window!

    let endedEditing = window.makeFirstResponder(window)
    if !endedEditing {
        Swift.print("Unable to end editing")
        return
    }

    let undo: UndoManager = undoManager!

    // Has an edit occurred already in this event?
    if undo.groupingLevel > 0 {
        // Close the last group
        undo.endUndoGrouping()
        // Open a new group
        undo.beginUndoGrouping()
    }

    // Create the object
    let airport = airportsArrayController.newObject() as! Airport

    // Add it to the array controller's contentArray
    airportsArrayController.addObject(airport)

    // Re-sort (in case the user has sorted a column)
    airportsArrayController.rearrangeObjects()

    // Get the sorted array
    let sortedAirports = airportsArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [Airport]

    // Find the object just added
    let row = sortedAirports.index(of: airport)!

    // Begin the edit in the first column
    airportsTableView.editColumn(0,
                         row: row,
                         with: nil,
                         select: true)
}

...

// MARK: - Accessors

@objc func insertObject(_ airport: Airport, inAirportsAtIndex index: Int) {

    // Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    let undo = self.undoManager!
    (undo.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self)
        as AnyObject).removeObjectFromAirportsAtIndex(index)
    if !undo.isUndoing {
        undo.setActionName("Add Airport")
    }
    airports.insert(airport, at: index)
}


@objc func removeObjectFromAirportsAtIndex(_ index: Int) {
    // variable to be used in each Deatils action method - not working yet
    currentAirportIndex = index

    let airport: Airport = airports[index]

    // Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    let undo: UndoManager = undoManager!
    (undo.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as AnyObject)
        .insertObject(airport, inAirportsAtIndex: index)
    if !undo.isUndoing {
        undo.setActionName("Remove Airport")
    }
    airports.remove(at: index)
}
```

The undo works well for Add/Remove and editing of the Master table view - Airport. - (As a side note, I would like the undo menu button to say "undo editing" when undoing the editing, so I know I need to change the actionName in here somewhere for that.  I haven't worked on that part yet)

My current problem is that I have not been able to get the undo to work for the Details table views for Add/Remove nor editing.  The responder chain moves to the Details table views as expected.  I’m not sure of the correct way to get this done.  I tried overloading the insertObject(*::) and removeObjectFrom…(*:) methods.

```
// MARK: - Actions

@IBAction func addAirports(sender: NSButton) {
    let windowController = windowControllers[0]
    let window = windowController.window!

    let endedEditing = window.makeFirstResponder(window)
    if !endedEditing {
        Swift.print("Unable to end editing")
        return
    }

    let undo: UndoManager = undoManager!

    // Has an edit occurred already in this event?
    if undo.groupingLevel > 0 {
        // Close the last group
        undo.endUndoGrouping()
        // Open a new group
        undo.beginUndoGrouping()
    }

    // Create the object
    let airport = airportsArrayController.newObject() as! Airport

    // Add it to the array controller's contentArray
    airportsArrayController.addObject(airport)

    // Re-sort (in case the user has sorted a column)
    airportsArrayController.rearrangeObjects()

    // Get the sorted array
    let sortedAirports = airportsArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [Airport]

    // Find the object just added
    let row = sortedAirports.index(of: airport)!

    // Begin the edit in the first column
    airportsTableView.editColumn(0,
                         row: row,
                         with: nil,
                         select: true)
}


@IBAction func addGroundFrequencies(sender: NSButton) {
    let windowController = windowControllers[0]
    let window = windowController.window!

    let endedEditing = window.makeFirstResponder(window)
    if !endedEditing {
        Swift.print("Unable to end editing")
        return
    }

    // **** I think this is where I need to add a sub group of undo?

//      let undo: UndoManager = undoManager!
//      
//      // Has an edit occurred already in this event?
//      if undo.groupingLevel > 0 {
//          // Close the last group
//          undo.endUndoGrouping()
//          // Open a new group
//          undo.beginUndoGrouping()
//      }


    let groundFrequency = groundFrequenciesArrayController.newObject() as! GroundFrequency
    groundFrequenciesArrayController.addObject(groundFrequency)
    groundFrequenciesArrayController.rearrangeObjects()
    let sortedGroundFrequencies
        = groundFrequenciesArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [GroundFrequency]
    let row = sortedGroundFrequencies.index(of: groundFrequency)!
    groundFrequenciesTableView.editColumn(0,
                                  row: row,
                                  with: nil,
                                  select: true)
}

// MARK: - Accessors

@objc func insertObject(_ airport: Airport, inAirportsAtIndex index: Int) {

    // Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    let undo = self.undoManager!
    (undo.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self)
        as AnyObject).removeObjectFromAirportsAtIndex(index)
    if !undo.isUndoing {
        undo.setActionName("Add Airport")
    }
    airports.insert(airport, at: index)
}


@objc func removeObjectFromAirportsAtIndex(_ index: Int) {
    // variable to be used in each Deatils action method - not working yet
    currentAirportIndex = index

    let airport: Airport = airports[index]

    // Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    let undo: UndoManager = undoManager!
    (undo.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as AnyObject)
        .insertObject(airport, inAirportsAtIndex: index)
    if !undo.isUndoing {
        undo.setActionName("Remove Airport")
    }
    airports.remove(at: index)
}



// **** these functions are never called

@objc func insertObject(_ groundFrequency: GroundFrequency,
                                 inGroundFrequenciesAtIndex index: Int) {

    // Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    let undo = self.undoManager!
    (undo.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self)
        as AnyObject).removeObjectFromGoundFrequenciesAtIndex(index)
    if !undo.isUndoing {
        undo.setActionName("Add Ground Frequency")
    }
    airports[currentAirportIndex].groundFrequencies.insert(groundFrequency, at: index)
}


@objc func removeObjectFromGroundFrequenciesAtIndex(_ index: Int) {
    let groundFrequency: GroundFrequency = airports[currentAirportIndex].groundFrequencies[index]

    let undo: UndoManager = undoManager!
    (undo.prepare(withInvocationTarget: self) as AnyObject)
        .insertObject(groundFrequency, inGroundFrequenciesAtIndex: index)
    if !undo.isUndoing {
        undo.setActionName("Remove Ground Frequency")
    }
    airports[currentAirportIndex].groundFrequencies.remove(at: index)
}
```

The methods insertObject(_ groundFrequency::) and removeObjectFromGroundFrequenciesAtIndex(_ :) never get called.  So I’m sure this isn’t correct.  When I run it, I add an Airport, then Add a Ground frequency.  The undo still operates on Airport.  Even while the responder is still active in the ground Frequency table.

I’m not sure how to set up undo to work with the Details array controllers and associated table view.  Once I’ve got that figured out, I then need to know how to add the edit undo to them.

I’ve tried researching nesting undoManager but can’t really find anything that helps.  That might not even be what I need to do here.

I tried adding the following code to get the edit undo to work.  As stated previously, undo works on editing for the Master table, but not for the Details (groundFrequency) table view.

```
private var KVOContext: Int = 0
private var currentAirportIndex = 0


class Document: NSDocument, NSWindowDelegate {

...


// commented sections below did nothing.

@objc dynamic var airports: [Airport] = [] {
    willSet {
        for airport in airports {
//              for groundFrequency in airport.groundFrequencies {
//                  stopObservingGroundFrequency(groundFrequency: groundFrequency)
//              }
            stopObservingAirport(airport: airport)
        }
    }
    didSet {
        for airport in airports {
            startObservingAirport(airport: airport)
//              for groundFrequency in airport.groundFrequencies {
//                  startObservingGroundFrequency(groundFrequency: groundFrequency)
//              }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Key Value Observing

func startObservingAirport(airport: Airport) {
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "airportCode",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "gateServices",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "pushCall",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "companyMaintenanceAvailable",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "walkAroundRequired",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "dAtis",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "pdc",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "cpdlc",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "companyOpsFrequency",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "clearanceFrequency",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "mxFrequency",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)
    airport.addObserver(self,
                        forKeyPath: "atopsFrequency",
                        options: .old,
                        context: &KVOContext)

}


func stopObservingAirport(airport: Airport) {
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "airportCode")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "gateServices")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "pushCall")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "companyMaintenanceAvailable")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "walkAroundRequired")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "dAtis")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "pdc")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "cpdlc")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "companyOpsFrequency")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "clearanceFrequency")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "mxFrequency")
    airport.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "atopsFrequency")
}


func startObservingGroundFrequency(groundFrequency: GroundFrequency) {
    groundFrequency.addObserver(self,
                                forKeyPath: "groundSector",
                                options: .old,
                                context: &KVOContext)
    groundFrequency.addObserver(self,
                                forKeyPath: "groundFrequency",
                                options: .old,
                                context: &KVOContext)
}


func stopObservingGroundFrequency(groundFrequency: GroundFrequency) {
    groundFrequency.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "groundSector")
    groundFrequency.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "groundFrequency")
}


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                           of object: Any?,
                           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                           context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if context != &KVOContext {
        // If context does not match, this message must be intended for the super class
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                           of: object,
                           change: change,
                           context: context)
        return
    }


    var oldValue: AnyObject? = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.oldKey] as AnyObject
    if oldValue is NSNull {
        oldValue = nil
    }

    let undo: UndoManager = undoManager!
    (undo.prepare(withInvocationTarget: object as Any) as AnyObject)
        .setValue(oldValue, forKeyPath: keyPath!)
}
```

Here is the code for Airport and GroundFrequency if it's needed:

```
@objc(Airport)
class Airport: NSObject, NSCoding {

@objc dynamic var airportCode: String? = "Airport"
@objc dynamic var gateServices: Bool = true
@objc dynamic var pushCall: Bool = true
@objc dynamic var companyMaintenanceAvailable: Bool = false
@objc dynamic var walkAroundRequired: Bool = true
@objc dynamic var dAtis: Bool = true
@objc dynamic var pdc: Bool = true
@objc dynamic var cpdlc: Bool = true

@objc dynamic var companyOpsFrequency: String = "Freq"
@objc dynamic var clearanceFrequency: String = "Freq"
@objc dynamic var mxFrequency: String = "Freq"
@objc dynamic var atopsFrequency: String = "Freq"

@objc dynamic var groundFrequencies: [GroundFrequency] = []  
@objc dynamic var towerFrequencies: [TowerFrequency] = []
@objc dynamic var rampFrequencies: [RampFrequency] = []
@objc dynamic var atisFrequencies: [AtisFrequency] = []
@objc dynamic var vorFrequencies: [VorFrequency] = []
@objc dynamic var ilsFrequencies: [IlsFrequency] = []
@objc dynamic var departureProcedures: [DepartureProcedure] = []
@objc dynamic var singleEngineProcedures: [SingleEngineProcedure] = []
@objc dynamic var hudData: [HudData] = []


// MARK: - NSCoding

...

}



@objc(GroundFrequency)
class GroundFrequency: NSObject, NSCoding {

@objc dynamic var groundSector: String? = "Sector"  // East, West, North, South
@objc dynamic var groundFrequency = "Freq"


// MARK: - NSCoding

...

}
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction to get undo to work for each Details interface table view?

**Edit** 10/19 -  Or maybe I'm on the complete wrong track here and need to go about the design of this project in a different way?

Comment: The groundFrequency methods aren't called because `groundFrequencies` is a property of `Airport`. Is `observeValue` called when you add a groundFrequency? Consider using Core Data, you'll get undo for free.

Comment: No, observeValue isn't called for groundFrequency either.  I'll look deeper into Core Data.  I briefly looked at Core Data for this last month or the moth before, but couldn't figure out how to add an array as an attribute for Airport, and maybe with Core Data I don't need to think of it that way.  I'll revisit that and do more research on how to get it to work.  Thanks again Willeke.

Comment: An array attribute is a (ordered) to-many relationship.